# How to use UART pins on Orange Pi zero?

Tags: uart, armbian

I want to use UART1 or 2 (see picture) on the Orange Pi zero. But when I try to open the port with `screen /dev/ttyS1`

Screen terminates.

I found [here](https://forum.armbian.com/index.php?/topic/3651-uart-on-orange-pi-zero/) that I needed to add `"overlays=sun8i-h3-uart1"` in `/boot/armbianEnv.txt` but someone on that forum said that that feature is not yet supported. I tried, but I still have the same problem.

Any suggestions?

[image: Orange Pi Zero pinout]

```
uname -a
Linux orangepizero 4.11.9-sun8i #1 SMP Thu Jul 13 16:09:43 CEST 2017 
armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My config on Orange Pi Zero for UART on mainline kernel:

```
overlay_prefix=sun8i-h3
overlays=usbhost2 usbhost3 uart1 uart2
```

Both UARTs work fine.

```
$ uname -a
Linux orangepizero 4.13.16-sunxi #20 SMP Fri Nov 24 19:50:07 CET 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: So, could be this issue related to kernel version? (Dmitry is on the 4.13 kernel series while MatMis is on 4.11)...